# Connecting to a webSocket server in c#

Tags: c#, node.js, websocket, server, websocket-sharp

I am trying to connect to a webSocket server on port 2998 using the c# package websocket-sharp.

On the client side I am using the following code (written in c#):

```cs
WebSocket webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:2998");
webSocket.Connect();
webSocket.Send("test");
```

On the server side i am using node.js running the following code (written in typescript):

```js
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
const wss = new WebSocketServer({
    port: 2998,
});

wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
    console.log("connected")
    ws.on('error', console.error);

    ws.on('message', function message(data) {
        console.log('received: %s', data);
    });

    ws.send('something');
})
```

I expected to see `connected` and `test` logged in the terminal on the server side, but nothing is being logged. If you can provide me with a solution or help of any kind it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the package I was using does not work, if you are trying to use websocket-sharp in Unity i would recommend switching to [NativeWebSocket](https://github.com/endel/NativeWebSocket) it does the same thing, but it actually works.